# Как запустить метод mBillingClient(); в другом классе (нужно в MainActivity)

Tags: java, android

Так не получается

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 Main2Activity a = new Main2Activity();
        a.mBillingClient();
        }

    }
```

//

```
beginning of crash

    2019-11-03 13:56:43.506 25675-25675/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: dima113xxx.testplaybillinglibrary, PID: 25675
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dima113xxx.testplaybillinglibrary/dima113xxx.testplaybillinglibrary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
```

//

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            mBillingClient();
        }

        private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
        private String mSkuId1 = "MskuId_1";
        private String mSkuId2 = "MskuId_2";
        private BillingClient mBillingClient;

        public void mBillingClient() {
            mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                        //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка

                        List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                        for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                            String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();
                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete();
                            }

                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete2();
                            }}

                    }

                }
            }).build();
            mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                    if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                        querySkuDetails();
                        List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                        for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                            String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete();
                            }

                            if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                                payComplete2();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
                }
            });
        }



        private void querySkuDetails() {
            SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
            skuList.add(mSkuId1);
            skuList.add(mSkuId2);
            skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                    if (responseCode == 0) {
                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                            mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void Start(View view) {
            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId1))
                    .build();
            mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
        }

        public void Start2(View view) {
            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId2))
                    .build();
            mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
        }


        public void payComplete() {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean( "loadUr1" , true);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public void payComplete2() {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean( "loadUr2" , true);
            editor.apply();
        }


        private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
            Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
            return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
        }

    }
```

---

я пытаюсь создать отдельный класс но у меня 3 ошибки
ругается на (this) и getSharedPreferences

//

```
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
```

//

```
 mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
```

//

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

//

```
public class mBillingClient {

    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
    private String mSkuId1 = "mSkuId1";
    private String mSkuId2 = "mSkuId2";
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    public void mBillingClient() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                    //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка

                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();
                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }}

                }

            }
        }).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                    querySkuDetails();
                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
            }
        });
    }



    private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(mSkuId1);
        skuList.add(mSkuId2);
        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId1))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }

    public void Start2(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId2))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }


    public void payComplete() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr1" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void payComplete2() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr2" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }


    private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    }

}
```

Comment: нельзя запустить метод в другой Activity из текущей. Вы перемещайте его в какой-то класс отдельный, без привязке к UI

Comment: * другой activity

Comment: Все хорошо но есть еще одна ошибка ругается также на this mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow( activity: this, billingFlowParams);

Comment: Передайте параметром метода вызывающую активность и используйте вместо `this`. Метод: `public void mBillingClient(Activity activity)`, вызов его из активности: `mBillingClient(this)`, в методе: `mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);`